# Как проиграть анимацию при нажатии кнопки не используя триггер

Tags: wpf, c#

```
есть анимация Animation_vse_ok и анимация Animation_oshibka_avtorizacii
и при нажатии кнопки, если авторизация прошла нормально, то проигрываем одну анимацию, а если нет- то другую.
Как проиграть определённую анимацию? как я понял триггеры нажатия тут не покатят(ну а если и можно, то в этом примере 2 анимации, а как быть,если их много и нужна какая-нибудь логика для их проигрывания)
```

Comment: doubleanimation, гугли, читай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML =

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="animation_1">

        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="animation_2">

        </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

CODE =

```
Storyboard story = this.Resources["animation_1"] as Storyboard;
story.Begin();
```

Есть еще много вариантов, один из них - State. Но думаю, что этого вполне достаточно для большинства задач.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало, только я вместо BeginAnimation() записал Begin() (С тем не работало). и если кому понадобится это, не забудьте добавить пространство имён using System.Windows.Media.Animation;